# how to cancel the pending download task using NSURLSession in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession

I am creating a iPhone app which download icons using NSURLSession & NSURLDownloadTask.
In this case i want to download only the visible cell icons, when i scrolled the table all pending downloadTask get canceled (i.e download task for non-visible cells is must cancel). For this i created a method terminateAllDownloads().

```
// terminateAllDownloadTask 

-(void)terminateAllDownloads
{
    NSArray *allDownloads = [self.iconDownloadInProgress allValues];
    [allDownloads makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(cancelDownload)];

     [self.iconDownloadInProgress removeAllObjects];
}

// cancelDownload
-(void)cancelDownload
{

[self.downloadTask cancel];
[self.session invalidateAndCancel];

}
```

and call this function in dealloc & didRecieveMemoryWarning methods of MasterViewController.m

```
// dealloc
-(void)dealloc
{
   [self terminateAllDownloads];
}

// didReceiveMemeoryWarning
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  [self terminateAllDownloads];
}
```

but this method is not called single time. how should i do this ?

I am using the NSURLSession Delegates, not completion block

```
//code 
-(void)startDownload
{
    appDelgate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.fileName = self.appData.name;
    self.iconURL = self.appData.iconURL;
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration   defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = NO;
    _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
     self.downloadTask = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_iconURL]];

     [_downloadTask resume];
 }

 -(void)cancelDownload
 {
    [self.downloadTask cancel];
    [self.session invalidateAndCancel];
 }

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
 {
     NSString *trimmedString = [_fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

     NSString *appIconDirectory = [[documentsDirectoryForAppIcons absoluteString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appIcons"];
     NSURL* destinationUrlForAppIcon = [[NSURL URLWithString:appIconDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",trimmedString, @".png"]];

     NSError *error1;

     if([appIconFileManager fileExistsAtPath:[destinationUrlForAppIcon absoluteString]])
    {
       [appIconFileManager removeItemAtPath:[destinationUrlForAppIcon absoluteString] error:NULL];
    }

    BOOL status = [appIconFileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:destinationUrlForAppIcon error:&error1];
   if (status && !error1)
   {

     [appDelgate.downloadedIcons setValue:destinationUrlForAppIcon.path forKey:self.iconURL];

       if(self.completionHandler)
       {
          self.completionHandler(destinationUrlForAppIcon);
       }
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"File copy failed: %@", [error1 localizedDescription]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you refer to `self` in the block passed to the `NSURLSession` producing a retain cycle.

Comment: Hi Amin ... Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: Imagine, that you store the session in an instance. Then you start a task with a completion handler and the completion handler refers to `self`: The instance retains the session, the session retains the task, the task retains the instance …